# Running a program as an admin from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I'm trying to run a program as a an admin from a batch file.

A shortcut on my desktop is set to run `cmd` as an admin. I want to then run my command from this command prompt window.

```
@echo off

call /k \\c:\Users\Adam Wilson\Desktop\Cmd-Admin.lnk

START /k "netsh wlan start hostednetwork"
```

It does not run the command, and i am unsure of the command to put before it; whether its start, call, run or whatever. I just want it to open cmd, then run that commmand.

Thanks in advance and hope i have made myself clear.

Comment: This won't work. What happens is your link opens a separate (second) command shell, and then  the `START` command executes in the current (first) one, not in the new administrative one.

Comment: I see, is there anyway to run the command in the newly opened admin window?

Comment: Will this even work?: `call /k \\c:\Users\Adam Wilson\Desktop\Cmd-Admin.lnk` `call` does not have any options that I know of, and a quick check at the command prompt generates an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will start your lnk and execute the command, but I suspect not with the security settings of the .lnk:

```
start "title" "c:\Users\Adam Wilson\Desktop\Cmd-Admin.lnk" /K netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

If you don't want the window to hang around after completing the netsh command:

```
start "title" "c:\Users\Adam Wilson\Desktop\Cmd-Admin.lnk" /C netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Replace "title" with some nice title that you like...

Comment: Thanks this worked, but in the end i just created a task to run a normal bat file on every startup and changed it to have the highest rights, thanks anyway.